# Why does reloading page in Firefox or Chrome cause the unload event handler to trigger after the browser calls the server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I noticed something odd in the way Firefox and Chrome handle reloads, and I was wondering if anybody else has encountered this and perhaps knows why.

I have a `window.onunload` event where I set a cookie (in this case using YUI, but native JS or jQuery would work the same). This cookie normally gets sent in the HTTP request to the server, where the server-side code looks for it.  If the cookie exists, it can take a special action.

```
window.onunload = function() {
    Y.Cookie.set('reset_function', 'true', { path: '/'}); 
}
```

This works fine when the user is going from one page to another page via a link on the page.  However, when the user reloads the page, the cookie is being set in Firefox and Chrome (i.e. I verified the code is being executed via Firebug/Chrome DevTools), but the cookie is NOT sent to the server, so the server can't take the special action.

Has anybody encountered this and know why?  Is this behavior baked into these two browsers?

EDIT: When I debugged this further, on reload, Chrome and Firefox go to the server first and then go through the onunload event handler.  I'm still unsure why the browser behaves like this.

Comment: Could it be getting the page from cache?

Comment: I don't think it is the cache, because there are other browser cookies that are being sent in the reload.  I also disabled the browser cache in Chrome, and it didn't send that cookie, but it still got set when the page reloaded.

Comment: [_“The unload event is raised when the window is unloading its content and resources.”_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload) – when the user clicks a link that takes a while to load, the document does not immediately go “blank” and shows nothing until the new content arrives (would not be nice for the user to stare at a blank screen for that time) – so “unloading” the window’s content and resources before that would not make sense.

Comment: When clicking on a link on a page, the onunload event triggers before the request to the server happens.  However, when I hit reload, the request to the server happens before the onunload even triggers.  So, your statement isn't completely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but my guess would be that it's just a performance optimization.

First, you should be aware that the `onunload` method is (last I checked) not allowed to prevent the user from navigating off the page. If it were, I think there'd be a lot more malicious inescapable websites!

What it *can* do (on some browsers, anyway) is prompt the user with a message, and give the *user* the opportunity to cancel navigation.

Since this prompt takes some non-zero amount of time, the browser developers (for Chrome and Firefox) may have decided to go ahead and make the request first, so that if the user pauses for a moment and then confirms, the subsequent page will load as fast as possible.

I don't really know if this is accurate or not, but it's one possible explanation. Note that the `onunload` method is [not part of any standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onunload), which means its behavior isn't exactly clearly defined anyway, which means the browser makers are free to put the request before or after the event handler, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  This is a web application where we need to warn the end user, and allow the user to cancel the reload/page exit.  We do use the return statement in the onbeforeunload event to prompt the user to cancel leaving the page.  However, I was confused as to why a reload behaved differently than clicking a link on a page to leave.  Given what you said and what I have observed on page reload, I may simply leave the onunload event to cleanup work and not actually set anything of value.